# Angular2 RxJS reply corrent http requests periodically (polling)

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I use Angular2 2.4.8. I fetch data using `Http` service:

```
fetchData(urls: string[], computer: Computer): Observable<Computer> {
    let stream$ = <Subject<Computer>>new Subject();
    let requests = new Map<string, Observable<Response>>();
    urls.forEach(url => {
        requests.set(url, this.http.get(url));
    });
    Observable.forkJoin(Array.from(requests, x => x[1]))
        .subscribe((responses: Response[]) => {
            // put data from responses into computer (API gives data in pieces)
            stream$.next(computer);
            stream$.complete();
        },
        (e: Response) => {
            // do something with error
            stream$.error(e.json());
        });
    return stream$.asObservable();
}
```

Now I need to refresh data periodically (polling). The difficulty is that the frequency should be different for different urls. Can I achieve this using Rx?

Maybe instead of parameter `urls: string[]` I could pass array of objects with url and fefresh frequuency. But I don't know how to solve this in Rx.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to periodically make HTTP requests, you need to use `.interval`. This will allow you to "trigger" a new request now and then.

For example:

```js
function poll (tuple) {
  return Rx.Observable.combineLatest(
    tuple.map(({url, time}) => {
      return Rx.Observable
        .interval(time)
        .switchMap(val => Rx.Observable.of(`${url}: ${val}`));
    })
  );
}

poll([
  { url: 'foo', time: 500 },
  { url: 'bar', time: 100 }
]).subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Replace the `Rx.Observable.of` part with your `http` service.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on what exactly you're trying to do and how you want to handle the Observable returned from `fetchData()`.

In general, if you want to periodically repeat a request you can use the `repeatWhen()` operator and chain it with `delay()`:

```
urls.forEach(url => {
    requests.set(url, this.http.get(url)
      .repeatWhen(notifier => notifier.delay(XXX)));
});
```

Also, if you want to repeat the requests you can't use the `forkJoin()` because it'll just emit values and complete immediately.

In this case both [`combineLatest()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-combineLatest) or [`zip()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-zip) seems good depending on what you want to achieve.